# Quicklook all unassociated files as text QLStephen doesn't work

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, quicklook

Currently some filetypes have their own quicklook associations already, e.g. `.mp4` files quicklook with some lite quicktime player, and `.jpg` files quicklook as an image.

How can I make every unassociated file quicklook as if it were text?

Commonly I have lots of programming or markup sourcefiles that I want to quickly inspect contents of.

I have installed QuickLook Stephen, but it only seems to work for the files it specifically says it works for (README, package.json,— it's NOT working for arbitrary unassociated files, in my case these are files like *.cs, *.csproj, *.yml)

Comment: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-should-we-get-a-question-updated-for-a-new-version

Comment: Please add a bounty to the original question to get more up-to-date answers. This will keep all answers at the same place and not distributed over several questions.